Read operation timing out error with google drive api
When I am attempting to upload images to a google drive folder through my Python Flask web server using Google API, setting their permissions, and creating a spreadsheet with simple attributes that I have collected from the image, I get a read operation timed out error. It happens randomly for random images every time and throughout debugging I noticed it typically happens with the .create google api call. Regardless of where the error occurs, the images always all end up getting uploaded to the drive, but the image where the read operation timed out error occurs does not get an entry in the spreadsheet.
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheet_id = find_spreadsheet(drive_service, master_folder_id, master_folder_name)
if not spreadsheet_id:
spreadsheet_id = create_spreadsheet(sheets_service, master_folder_id, master_folder_name)

headers = \['Image', 'Image ID'\] + data_points_names
app.logger.debug(f"Headers: {headers}") # Log headers
add_headers_if_empty(sheets_service, spreadsheet_id, headers)

data = \[\] # Spreadsheet data

for image_id, file in files.items():
file_stream = io.BytesIO(file.read())
file_metadata = {
'name': file.filename,
'parents': \[folder_id\]
}
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(file_stream, mimetype=file.mimetype, resumable=True)
try:
file_drive = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
file_id = file_drive.get("id")
app.logger.debug(f'File ID: {file_id}')

        permission = {
            'type': 'anyone',
            'role': 'reader'
        }
    
        drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=file_id, body=permission).execute()
        app.logger.debug(f'Permissions set for file ID: {file_id}')
    
        file_link = f"https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id={file_id}&authuser=0"
    
        real_image_id = str(image_id.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
        # app.logger.debug(f"Real image ID: {real_image_id}")
    
        # collect data points for this image
        row = [file_link, file_id]
        if real_image_id in data_points_values:
            # app.logger.debug(f"length of data point names: {len(data_points_names)}")
            for i in range(len(data_points_names)):
                # app.logger.debug(f"data: {data_points_values[real_image_id].get(str(i))}")
                row.append(data_points_values[real_image_id].get(str(i)))
    
        app.logger.debug(f"Row: {row}")
        data.append(row)
    
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f'Error uploading file: {e}')

if data:
    append_to_spreadsheet(sheets_service, spreadsheet_id, data)

And here are the screenshots of the error messages:
When uploading files and setting permissions lead to read operation timed out and
When creating a spreadsheet leads to read operation timed out
